# How to make PHP getter/setter inherit DocBlock from their field?

Tags: php, phpstorm, docblocks

How can I make getter/setter methods to automatically use DocBlock description from their respective fields? Or maybe there are any other ways to solve this: see DocBlocks on getters/setters without manually copy-pasting every single one.

Consider this example:
[image]

There is some comment on field `$name` (1), however, it will almost never be seen as the field is private and intended to be used with getter/setter methods. However, on those methods IDE does not show any comments from field variables (2).

You can, of course, simply copy-paste same description to both methods. But it becomes very difficult to manage when object has a dozen or more properties, all with getters/setters and extensively commented. It requires a lot of manual work to fix the same text in 3 places on every change and is very error-prone.

IDE is PhpStorm.
I'd prefer to do it without magic `__get` `__set` methods.

Comment: AFAIK -- you cannot. `@inheritDoc` tag works with parents only (e.g. to copy (inherit) description from the same method in the parent class).

Comment: I'm aware of that :( was thinking maybe there are at least some dirty workarounds, or IDE-specific hacks.

Comment: I'm not aware about IDE-specific hanks here. I may suggest submitting a Feature Request ticket to the [PhpStorm Issue Tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI) . Your request/desired functionality certainly makes sense to me. E.g. "using some tag (e.g. `@see` or whatnot) show such description from that field when invoking documentation on such method"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only option I know is using `@see` or `@link`. We can use them inline as well. This is how it looks in Phpstorm:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfSg4.png]

The link in the description is clickable. Without a mouse, we can use a tab key to move a cursor on the link (3 x tab and enter).

[image: First popup]

Final view:

[image: Final popup]

Comment: We can remove dollar sign using description. 

```Set {@see $name name}```